# Problem with onItemClick

Tags: android

This might be really long and I'm sorry for the poor soul who reads through it all.

Goal: I want to create a Pokemon Pokedex application (Yeah I know very childish). I thought this would be great for a first application to build because there is tons of data to deal with. For those not familiar with Pokemon it's basically creatures in a list from #001 - #649. I want to display all the creatures in a list and have the user click on that creature. Once the creature is clicked on it will display statistics about it on a different screen.

Ok back to programming...

```
package com.pokemon.pokdex;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class PokedexActivity extends ListActivity {
     @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setListAdapter(ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getApplicationContext(),
                    R.array.pokemon_titles, R.layout.list_item));

            final String[] links = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.pokemon_stats);

            getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    String content = links[position];
                }
            });
        }
}
```

I'm getting errors on  `getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {` where is says `OnItemClickListener()` and `View view`,. it says `The type new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){} must implement the inherited abstract method AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.onItemClick(AdapterView<?>, View, int, long)` for `OnItemClickListener()` and View cannot be resolved to a type for `View view,`

```
package com.pokemon.pokdex;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class PokedexViewActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.pokemon_stats);

        };
    }
```

On this file I'm getting an error on `setContentView(R.layout.pokemon_stats);` Here is the error `pokemon_stats cannot be resolved or is not a field`

My string.xml file looks like
(this is where the pokemon will be set as well as the stats. I did the first pokemon below.)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="hello">Pokemon Pokedex</string>
    <string name="app_name">Pokedex</string>
    <string-array name="pokemon_titles">
    <item>#001 - Bulbasaur</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="pokemon_stats">
    <item>Grass Type</item>
</string-array>
</resources>
```

My main.xml looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/hello"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

My list_item.xml looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="24dp"
android:padding="6dp" />
```

Any help is appreciated and thank you if you made it this far :)

EDIT: Updated and added the exact errors I'm getting.

Comment: you should add the exact errors you receive. I can't figure out if they are compile-time or runime-error either. Be precise where the error occurs and give the full stack traces.

Comment: It's giving me the errors as if they are syntax errors. I'm not even compiling yet.

Comment: what do error say ? (on mouve over)

Comment: I updated for the errors

Comment: Just so you know, you won't be able to release this app on the market. There was a great one, called PokeDroid, but TPC (the pokemon company) asked him to take it down, as they felt it was infringing on their printed media and strategy guides.

Comment: Yeah I figured as much. It's kind of like my own little project and I will give it to friends who play. Not a big deal if it's not on the market.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your error `setContentView(R.layout.pokemon_stats);` pokemon_stats is not a layout. main.xml is your layout. pokemon_stats is a string array, that's your problem. There is no layout called pokemon_stats.xml, I think you want `R.layout.main`.

Also, why do you have a semi-colon after `}` here?

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.pokemon_stats);

    };
```

**Edit:** At the top of your other error, the one with view, you forgot to import android.view.View; add this. You can keep your original code.

```
import android.view.View;
```

That should be it, really.

Comment: I honestly don't know why there is a semi colon there. This fixed my that error but still need the View view on the PokedexActivity to not error out. Thanks for the answer and sorry for the long read. :)

Comment: Sorry, wrong answer. Add this import, it's what you're missing. import android.view.View; Or see my edit.

Answer (score 2):

Try now

```
package com.pokemon.pokdex;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

    public class PokedexActivity extends ListActivity {
         @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

                setListAdapter(ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getApplicationContext(),
                        R.array.pokemon_titles, R.layout.list_item));

                });
            }
           @Override
           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position, long id) {
               final String[] links = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.pokemon_stats);
                        String content = links[position];        
           }

    }
```

Comment: This worked for one of the errors. I still have an error on the View view on the OnItemClick()

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any ID on the textView you are using to hold the information, where is this information going to be displayed?

Also, for your resources, your data should really be held in a single array with CSV or something, it will be much simpler than holding different information in different arrays.  Parse the data in with tags or by array order, and bind them to your view that way.

Your main.xml is going to be what is displayed here, as well.  If you don't have anything defined for main.xml, the program is going to error out.  setContentView() sets the content view for the ENTIRE screen.  If you want to add an item to a view, use View.addItem(Layout).

Hope this helps.  It's the best I can do without any error messages!